# PHP : Why extracted zip filename is changed for Japanese characters in lhaplus software?

Tags: php, laravel, zip, 7zip

I am working on zip file creation and downloading using PHP (Laravel).
Zip created and download works well. But the problem is in **lhaplus** software. When extracting the zip file using **lhaplus**, it has been changing the file name. But in another extractor like 7zip, WinRAR works well. In **lhaplus** software shows "03510063220_00016501tñ+sÉìtñ+sÉì_spt.pdf" but it should be 03510063220_00016501社名社名_spt.pdf.

Please help in this case. Any suggestion is appreciated.

The code is given below:

```
$date_time = static::getCurrentTime();
$zip_name = $date_time."_spt";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if(!file_exists('zip/downloadedZip')){
    mkdir('zip/downloadedZip',0777,true);
}

$zipFileName = 'zip/downloadedZip/'.$zip_name.'.zip';


if ($zip->open(public_path($zipFileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE){
    $fileName = "pdf/03510063220_00016501社名社名_spt.pdf";
    $baseName = "03510063220_00016501社名社名_spt.pdf";
    if (!$zip->addFile($fileName, mb_convert_encoding($baseName, "SJIS", "UTF-8"))) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Add file failed: %s', $fileName));
    }
    $zip->close();
}

return URL($zipFileName);
```

Comment: First off: If you change `mb_convert_encoding($baseName, "SJIS", "UTF-8")` to `$baseName` , what happens ?

Comment: @KenLee When change mb_convert_encoding($baseName, "SJIS", "UTF-8") to $baseName,  output is same.

Comment: Is `lhaplus` a japanese software ? (follow-up: So if you use normal softwares like Winrar/7zip , everything will be ok ?)

Comment: Yes, lhaplus is japanese software. Winrar/7zip everything works well.